# Django: Set datetime in views to utc+1

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have checked around a bit, both here and Google, without finding an exact answer to what I'm looking for.

I'm currently working on a Django-project and I seem to live in one of those areas where the concept of a timezone ain't regarded very highly. The timezone here is CEST, alternative: UTC+1, but neither can be set in my settings-file. I have searched around for how to change this, and one alternative is to download and include a library which should do the trick, after a bit of tweaking. But I wonder if there is a smoother, swifter way to do this.

`date = datetime.datetime.now()` gives me the time for two hours ago. I can use both UTC and GMT, but neither is close enough.

Comment: In your settings file, `USE_TZ=True` and `TIME_ZONE='CET'` should do the trick

Comment: Which actually worked out really well, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Marking the comment as an answer

In your settings file, `USE_TZ=True` and `TIME_ZONE='CET'` should do the trick

The documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE)

Here are a list of valid [timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 2):

Change TIME_ZONE value according to your timezone:

```
UTC-2 = 'Etc/GMT+2'
UTC-2 = 'Etc/GMT+1'
UTC = 'Etc/GMT+0'
UTC+1 = 'Etc/GMT-1'
UTC+2 = 'Etc/GMT-2'
```

Yes, the sign is inverted after GMT. For other timezones (example half hours extra) see the [TZ names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).